# How to have Chosen plugin retain selection option following page reload

Tags: entity-framework, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-chosen

I'm using a series of select elements on a form within an MVC5 view, initialised with the jQuery Chosen plugin. The plugin looks as it should and saves the selected option back to the model successfully. However if any other element on the page fails validation and the page is reloaded, the select elements are back to their original state and the selected option is no longer shown. How can I get the select list to retain its selected option following a reload?

```
<select class="chosen" id="SE_Visit1" name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.SE_Visit1)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">0 (25)</option>
    <option value="1">1 (23)</option>
    <option value="2">2 (37)</option>
    <option value="3">3 (34)</option>
    <option value="4">4 (12)</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function () {
    // initialise the Chosen plugin on the select lists
    $('.chosen').chosen({ placeholder_text_single: "Select visit...", width: "75px" });
});
```

I've tried to add a change event handler on the element to save the selected value which could be used to assign the value again after reload but this just seems to break the page. Any help much appreciated since this particular form has 20 select elements so a lot of values for the user to have to complete more than once.

Comment: Use the `Html.DropDownFor()` helper to generate your `<select>` element

Comment: I did try using Html.DropDownFor() but when it wasn't working right for me I tried changing to select and got the basic functionality I needed. Is using it likely to solve the problem with reload?

Comment: Using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` will give you correct 2 way model binding. What was it that was not working for you?

Comment: Get a 'View data item that has the key 'fieldname' is of type System.String (or System.Int16) but must be of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' error, and can't get the placeholder to display correctly. Have tried returning a new SelectList from the database and also building it manually with 'List.Add(new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text="TheOption" });' and passing them in the ViewBag, both from examples. Also tried helper two ways: '@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Field, (SelectList)ViewBag.Visits)' and '@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Field, ViewBag.Visits as SelectList)'.

Comment: You get that error because the value of `ViewBag.Visits` is `null` - probably because when you POST and return the view, you have not re-assigned the `ViewBag.Visits` value (as you did in the GET method)

Comment: Thanks for that, they're showing now on postback. I don't get the data-placeholder text, I assume because when I pull from the database I don't have the blank option first required by Chosen for displaying the default text. Is there a way to add that?

Comment: Not familiar with chosen, so not really sure